# faultEvent message body of HTTPService empty in Mozilla and Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, flex3, internet-explorer-8, mozilla, httpservice

I am using HTTPService for authentication in my appliaction and I am parsing the messahe body of faultEvent of fault handler to determine what fault is coming. Every thing is working fine in IE but in case of Chrome and Mozilla the message body of FaultEvent of faulthandler is coming empty.

Please suggest how can I handle faults in Mozilla and Chrome ?

Comment: Is anyone there who can help me out? It is very urgent. Some suggestion would definitely help further investigation.

Comment: We still are struggling with this issue. Any suggestion would definitely help further investigation.

Answer (score 0):

Had similar problem and found that flash gets from server only 'HTTP 200' responses. All faults are handled as faults without any messages forwarded. So, we 'invented' our own web-services, that add additional header. We always return status 200 for HTTP response, but add return code and message into our header.

Then we parse our custom header and have true response.

Also have read, that this problem is solved in newest flash player 10, but maybe still in development versions. And because we need to support also version 9, we keep using our custom headers.